# How can I get the name of the file on the current Dired line?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, shell, prefix-argument, wsl

I'm running emacs on WSL.

The following function launches the binary file marked in dired:

```
(defun wsl/execute ()
  "execute file at point in dired"
  (interactive)
  (dired-do-shell-command
   "cmd.exe /c start \"\""
   current-prefix-arg
   (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg)))
```

I would like to use `dired-get-file-for-visit` instead of `dired-get-marked-files` to skip the marking.

My attempt at this does not work:

```
(defun wsl/execute ()
  "execute file at point in dired"
  (interactive)
  (dired-do-shell-command
   "cmd.exe /c start \"\""
   current-prefix-arg
   (list (dired-get-file-for-visit))))
```

With the latter and `/e/Downloads/AnyDesk.exe` I get `Invalid switch - "/e".^M`

What am I missing from the second implementation?

**UPDATE**

For posterity, here are the final functions I'm using

```
(defun wsl/execute ()
  "execute file at point in dired"
  (interactive)
  (dired-do-shell-command
   "cmd.exe /c start \"\""
   current-prefix-arg
   (dired-get-marked-files t t)))
```

`Enter` on file to launch it or open it:

```
(defun wsl-p ()
  "Is the system WSL?"
  (and (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
       (string-match
        "Linux.*Microsoft.*Linux"
        (shell-command-to-string "uname -a"))))

(defun dired-find-file-or-execute (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Wrapper for dired-find-file that, on WSL, launches binaries instead of opening them"
  (interactive)
  (let ((file (dired-get-marked-files t t)))
    (if
        (and
         (wsl-p)
         (or (string-match-p "\.exe\\'" (first file))
             (string-match-p "\.bat\\'" (first file))
             (string-match-p "\.com\\'" (first file))))
        (dired-do-shell-command "cmd.exe /c start \"\"" current-prefix-arg (dired-get-marked-files t t))
      (apply orig-fun args))))

(advice-add 'dired-find-file :around #'dired-find-file-or-execute)
```

Comment: What does "does not work" actually mean?

Comment: Updated with failure case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, but I think you're asking how to have `dired-get-marked-files` pick up only the file named on the current line, instead of the files that are marked.

If so, the answer is to just use a prefix argument (`C-u 1`, `M-1`, or `C-1`, to tell it to use the next one file, or even just `C-u`, to tell it to use the file named on the current line).  The doc of the function tells you this:

> `dired-get-marked-files` is a compiled Lisp function in `dired.el`.
>
> `(dired-get-marked-files &optional LOCALP ARG FILTER DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED ERROR)`
>
> Return the marked files’ names as list of strings.
>
> The list is in the same order as the buffer, that is, the car is the
> first marked file.
>
> Values returned are normally absolute file names.
>
> Optional arg `LOCALP` as in `dired-get-filename`.
>
> Optional second argument `ARG`, if non-`nil`, specifies files near point instead of marked files.  It usually comes from the prefix argument.
>
> - If `ARG` is an integer, use the next `ARG` files.
> - If `ARG` is any other non-`nil` value, return the current file name.
> - If no files are marked, and `ARG` is `nil`, also return the current file name.
>
> Optional third argument `FILTER`, if non-`nil`, is a function to select some of the files--those for which (funcall FILTER FILENAME) is non-nil.
>
> If `DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED` is non-`nil`, then if we find just one marked file,
> return `(t FILENAME)` instead of `(FILENAME)`.
> Don’t use that together with `FILTER`.
>
> If `ERROR` is non-`nil`, signal an error when the list of found files is empty.
> `ERROR` can be a string with the error message.

Your (first) command passes the prefix arg, so it's likely OK as is. If not, you can explicitly pass a non-`nil` value as `ARG` in the call to `dired-get-marked-files`.

Comment: I thought I needed to use get-file-for-visit for the file at point but apparently not. 

Thanks!